# How do I get NPM install just one package?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, npm-install

I'm running Node 6.3.0 on a MackBook I just set up running OS X 10.11

I installed Node using Homebrew and I noticed that when I run `npm install` it installs what amounts to dozens and dozens of extra packages.

For instance when I run `npm install gulp --save` it installs gulp but when I look in the `node_modules` directory I see what looks like 30 or 40 extra folders. This is different then when I run npm at home on my Linux box. When I do that I only see the one directory.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: those are the dependencies the `gulp` requires to run.

Comment: your linux box has an out of date install of npm. It is doing the same thing, only, it's nesting all the additional components inside of sub node_modules folders. Newer versions of npm install things more... flatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of npm (< 3) on your Linux box. With npm 3 they changed the way they store dependencies and try to flatten the dependencies tree. e.g. If you had a project A that depends on B and B depends on C it would look like this:

npm 2:

```
A/node_modules/B/node_modules/C
```

npm 3:

```
A/node_modules/B
A/node_modules/C
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize this was happening on purpose. Thanks so much.